# How to make the table column size fixed

Tags: html

I have the following table in HTML

https://jsfiddle.net/xc1fm5uL/

but I'm unable to make the column widths fixed. I tried both

```
<col width="300">
<td width="300">
```

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: `<td style="width=300px;">` ?

Comment: The `width` attribute on `col` and `td` elements is [deprecated in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col). Use CSS instead either inline `style= "width: 300px"` or in your CSS file. Furthermore I suggest to [read up on tables and `table-layout: fixed`](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/).

Comment: I don't see any <col> in your html in your jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

read more on this @ [css3 tricks for fix table](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/)

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but that creates other problems I try my best not to remember.

Comment: @ycr glad it solved. Give a shot on https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/ too

Answer (score 1):

You can do it theses ways :

```
<td width="300px">
<td style="width:300px;">
```

But the best way is doing it in Css:

```
.class{width:300px;}
```

Hope it helps you
**Edit:**
both th and td should have the same width.